# Can't make menuconfig

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, debian, upgrade

I use Debian 7.4 Wheezy. I trying to upgrade my kernel, but when I type "make menuconfig" it says:

```
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 *** 
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 *** 
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

I trying to install "libncurses5-dev", but I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev
```

P.S.

I downloaded and installed the packages manually and now everything is okay! 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have run (as root)

```
aptitude update
aptitude search libncurses
```

that would suggest you the right package name.

Then try

```
aptitude install libncurses-dev
```

and

```
aptitude install kernel-package
aptitude build-dep linux-image linux-image-amd64
```

At last, use `make-kpkg --initrd binary` to compile your kernel. (it will produce `*.deb` files in the parent directory). You want to configure `/etc/kernel-pkg.conf` and perhaps `/etc/kernel-img.conf`

Comment: `i   libncurses5                     - shared libraries for terminal handling    
i   libncursesw5                    - shared libraries for terminal handling`

I get the same error after these commands..

When I type apt-get update libncurses5 libncursesw5 I get this massege
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libncursesw5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: `# aptitude install libncurses-dev
No candidate version found for libncurses-dev
No candidate version found for libncurses-dev
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
`

Comment: The thing that surprised me is that it needed the `-dev` package. I had `libncurses5` installed, and thought that would be enough. But it turned out that `libncurses5-dev` was needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case installation of package `libncursesw5-dev` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

make menuconfig needs ncurses libraries try following command to install ncurses library

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make menuconfig
```

worked for me after i installed all the libaries, and added myself sudo permission, i was also using this to cross_compile stuff

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

***%b37399 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL***

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora(Red Hat);

```
$ make menuconfig
#error encountered :
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:210: scripts/kconfig/mconf-cfg] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:588: menuconfig] Error 2
#resolution : 
$ sudo yum install libncurses-dev
```

Thanks

Comment: There are already other answers saying to install that lib, this is just a duplicate of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the project the menuconfig could be made with the `kconfiglib` library:

https://pypi.org/project/kconfiglib/

For these projects it's required to:

- Install Python (I tested it with Python2.7, but I think newer Pythons are just fine)
- Install pip (if it's not done with Python)
- And then the `pip install kconfiglib`

And for some projects, this will fix the error instead of the libcurses package.

Just as example here is one `kconfiglib` based project which prints the same error, but will not be fixed with libcurse:

https://github.com/polarfire-soc/hart-software-services